# Rally Or Filter on Release Start Date sdk

Tags: date, filter, sdk, customization, rally

I need help with the following code. The uncommented code works fine, but I need to get the commented code to work. See //value: releaseStartDateISO in my code below.  Specifically, filter-2 doesn't work. I want to display defects that are active (ie, filter 1- not closed) or defects with a Closed Date greater than Release Start Date (filter 2).  This will give me all active defects plus any that were closed during the current sprint.  I tried converting Release Start Date to ISO, but this doesn't work.  It seems like rally is not recognizing ReleaseStartDate and I don't know why. Note:  This is the code from rally git.  I added the "or filter" https://github.com/RallyApps/app-catalog/tree/master/src/apps/defectsummarymatrix
Thanks for your help!

```
        _showComponentIfNeeded: function(component) {
        if (component && component.isHidden()) {
            component.show();
        }
    },

    _initializeAllDefectStore: function(release) {
            //var releaseStartDate = release.get('ReleaseStartDate');
            //var releaseStartDateISO = Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(releaseStartDate,true);
            var filter = Ext.create('Rally.data.QueryFilter', {
                property: 'State',
                operator: '!=',
                value: 'Closed'
            });
                filter = filter.or({
                property: 'ClosedDate',
                operator: '>',
                //value: releaseStartDateISO
                value: '2014-09-10'
            });
              filter.toString();
            if (this.releaseFilter && this.defectModel) {
            this.allDefectStore = Ext.create('Rally.data.wsapi.Store', {
                model: this.defectModel, 
                fetch: ['State','Priority'],
                autoLoad: true,
                limit: Infinity,
                context: this.getContext().getDataContext(),
                filters : [this.releaseFilter,filter],
                listeners: {
                    load: this._onAllDefectStoreLoaded,
                    scope: this
                }
            });
        }
    },

    _onAllDefectStoreLoaded: function(store, records, successful, eOpts) {
        this._initializeMatrixTable();
        this._populateMatrixTable(records);
        this._createPriorityRecords(records);
        this._updateMatrixGrid();
        this.setLoading(false);
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of release.get('ReleaseStartDate')?  Is it possible the release record you have does not have that field populated?

Comment: I confirmed ReleaseStartDate is populated.  Thank you.

Comment: I confirmed ReleaseStartDate is populated from another app. However, I think I might need to add the UserStory model, but I tried in several places and either the syntax is wrong or it's in the wrong place. Thanks for your comment.